# syntax issue Manjaro 22, python 3.10 - Spyder-IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hope everyone is doing well.
So After I fixed my indention problem using Spyder I came with anoter problem.
After executing the script return with syntax issue.
The issue it is on the line "except KeyboardInterrupt:"
I cant fix the syntax problem.
Running the script on terminal give me the following result:   `except KeyboardInterrupt: ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
I hope someone can help me, here is the full code.

Best regards.

Code:

```
    for i in range(len(names)):
        try:
            name  = names[i].text.split('(')[0].replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\t','').strip()
            age  = ages[i].text.replace("age","Years old").strip()
            dictt = {'names' :name, 'age' :str(age)},
            names_ages.append(dictt)
        except:
            pass

    if len(names) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return names_ages

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return None
```

Comment: You have no `try` to go with `except`

Comment: Maybe that should be on the `try` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Hello I belive I fixied my problem but now ask for finally or excep block.
https://pastebin.com/Qc0dVchd

Comment: You have to put something after `except:`. If you don't want to do anything, use `pass` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange your code like this, you can’t leave an except block on its own without a try block.

```
    for i in range(len(names)):
        try:
            name  = names[i].text.split('(')[0].replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\t','').strip()
            age  = ages[i].text.replace("age","Years old").strip()
            dictt = {'names' :name, 'age' :str(age)},
            names_ages.append(dictt)
       
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return None

        except:
            pass

    if len(names) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return names_ages
```

Comment: You have to put `except keyboardInterrupt:` first. They're tested in order.